# Getting NEO4j Error "Expected Long(0) to be a org.neo4j.values.storable.TextValue, but it was a org.neo4j.values.storable.LongValue": 1

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I am new to neo4j database. I am trying to update specific nodes from existing nodes in graph db by loading csv file . my updated value csv file  look like this

```
ID,SHOPNAME,DIVISION,DISTRICT,THANA
01760,Xyz,RAJSHAHI,JOYPURHAT,Panchbibi
01761,Abc,DHAKA,GAZIPUR,Gazipur Sadar
```

and my query code

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///nodes_AGENT_U_20190610.csv" AS line return line','MERGE (p:Agent{ID:TOINT(line[0])}) ON MATCH SET p.SHOPNAME=TOINT(line[1]) ' ,{batchSize:10000, iterateList:true, parallel:true});
```

but I am getting  error

**"Expected Long(0) to be a org.neo4j.values.storable.TextValue, but it was a org.neo4j.values.storable.LongValue": 1**

I have tried TOINTEGER function   for resolving this problem but not working  for me , Kindly help me to solve this issue . I am using Neo4j 3.5 and apoc version 3.5.0.4
Thank you

Comment: Which version of Neo4j? 3.5.0? If so, upgrade to the latest 3.5.x patch release, to rule out any patched out bugs in earlier releases.

Comment: My neo4j version is Neo4j 3.5.6

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use `column name` to access value from the line/row, when loading data with `LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS`.

Check following query:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
"file:///nodes_AGENT_U_20190610.csv" AS line return line',
'MERGE (p:Agent{ID:TOINT(line.ID)}) 
ON MATCH SET p.SHOPNAME=TOINT(line.SHOPNAME) ' ,
{batchSize:10000, iterateList:true, parallel:true});
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with above answer, also some more knowledge, as you might be thinking i have seen that kind of usage somewhere:

You may however also use below query the way you were using but here you don't have headers that's why:
      LOAD CSV FROM 'https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.0/csv/artists-fieldterminator.csv' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR ';'
CREATE (:Artist { name: line[1], year: toInteger(line[2])})